# How to fix missing panel in Ubuntu Studio 19.10?

Tags: xfce, 19.10, panel, ubuntu-studio, xfce-panel

The top panel in Ubuntu studio vanished from my system. I have tried several suggested methods to restore it, but none have worked.

Today, I reinstalled the OS, but the panel is still gone. When I try to restore it with:

```
xfce4-panel -r
```

or open panel settings, I get an error message saying they failed and:

```
GDBus.error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
The name org.xfce.Panel was not provided by any .service files
```

I was getting that error both before and after reinstalling Ubuntu Studio.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

try running `xfce4-panel` once on the terminal. Works for me. I don't even know why that happened to me at one time. Probably needs to be launched again because it suddenly crashed, and it didn't have a way on restarting the program.

Comment: I  did try that, to no avail. I ended up doing a clean install which solved the issue. I later upgraded to 20.04 LTS, and just last week did a clean install of 20.10. (BTW, due to Ubuntu Studio's switch from xfce to kde, there's no online upgrade option for 20.10)

Comment: Worked for me today, running xfce4-panel& from terminal.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple workaround** which may help if `xfce4-panel -r` crashed

1. on the first terminal run `xfce4-panel`  which should launch panel
2. on the second terminal run `xfce4-panel -r`  which should restart panel
3. close both terminals

Comment: great lifehack, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the command as the root user. Running it as a normal user will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, closing all applications in the current session and upgrading to `xfce4-panel 4.18.4` solved the problem. However, I'm not entirely certain whether the upgrade was necessary.